# Manually deploy LetsEncrypt certificate to Kubernetes

Tags: certificates, kubernetes, letsencrypt

One of my systems (Rocky Linux 9) collects wildcard certificates from LetsEncrypt and distributes it to the various systems that require an SSL certificate.

I also have AWX running on Kubernetes (CentOS Stream 8) and I want to use the LetsEncrypt certificate for that system as well (So I DON'T want Kubernetes to manage the certificate)

How can I deploy the certificates to Kubernetes and which of the files cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem and privkey.pem are required?

Thanx in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

To add a certificate to a cluster, you add it as a secret (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: |
    <value>   
  tls.key: |
    <value>
```

Or using kubectl (with a guess based on your filenames): `kubectl create secret tls letsencrypt --cert=cert.pem --key=privkey.pem`

You can then reference that secret in the tls section of the ingress.